# How to insert data in sqlite database permanently

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created Sqlite database and all the tables required for my app and placed it in the assets folder. While accessing my app, I will insert data to all the tables in database. Now if I transfer the app via app sharing like Shareit, I am not able to see the data I inserted in the new app which I received. How to make the data permanent so that if I share the app, all the data added runtime also must be shared.

Comment: Simply use a remote database. The database is on a server instead of on a single device.

Answer (score -2):

To achieve it,

1. Place your data base into assets folder.
2. On splash page copy data base file from assets folder into project's database folder.

check if data base allready exist or not .

```
private void isDBExist() {

    String outFileName = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/"
            + DatabaseHandler.DATABASE_NAME;
    File f = new File(outFileName);
    if (!f.exists()) {
        f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        copyDataBase(DatabaseHandler.DATABASE_NAME);
    } 

}
```

if database not exist then copy data base file from asset folder into database folder.

```
private void copyDataBase(String DB_NAME) {
        // Open your local db as the input stream

        // ContextWrapper cw =new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        String DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
            DB_PATH = getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
        } else {
            DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        }

        InputStream myInput;

        Log.i("Database", "New database is being copied to device!");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        OutputStream myOutput = null;
        int length;
        // Open your local db as the input stream

        try {
            myInput = getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the
            // outputfile
            File f = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
            f.createNewFile();

            // dbFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();

            myOutput = new FileOutputStream(f);
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            myOutput.close();
            myOutput.flush();
            myInput.close();
            Log.i("Database", "New database has been copied to device!");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your answer cover this: `Now if I transfer the app via app sharing like Shareit, I am not able to see the data I inserted in the new app which I received. How to make the data permanent so that if I share the app, all the data added runtime also must be shared.`?

Comment: thanks for your quick reply Yogendra. Every time I open the new app, database is being copied from assets folder to database folder. Since there is no data attached to database in assets folder, nothing is getting copied. Is there any way to make database copied to databases folder permanent?

Comment: please add previous method  isDBExist(). it will check then will copy.